# Retrieving the index of selected <s:radio> inside an <s:iterator>

Tags: jsp, struts2

I want to retrieve the index of the selected radio button on my JSP page and pass it to my action class. The radio buttons are displayed as a column in a table on the JSP.

When I select any radio button and submit the form I want to get the index of the selected button in my action class.

```jsp
<s:iterator value="list" status="status">
    <tr>    
         <td>
             <s:radio name="listOption[%{#status.index}]" theme="simple"/>
         </td>
          <td>
             <s:textfield key="name" />
         </td>
           <td>
             <s:textfield key="salary" />
         </td>
     </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

The list is already populated. But I don't know how to get the selected row's index in my action when I submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden field to the form for the radio button.

```
 <s:hidden name="listIndex[%{#status.index}]" value="%{#status.index}"/>
```